# Is Sanitizing user input necessary when Request Validation is already on guard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

[Request Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh882339(v=vs.100).aspx) is a powerful mechanism to prevent injecting malicious code via a request to server. This is done on server-side so regardless of the fact that whether any client-side validation has done or not, one can be sure if something unusual is coming then an exception will be thrown automatically.

My question:
While we have "Request Validation" in hand, does it still necessary to sanitize requests?

I'm using Asp.net MVC 5.0

**PS:**
I'm solely talking in the context of web (not DB or something else) and its potential vulnerabilities (such as XSS).

Comment: Filtering non-harmful requests doesn't necessarily mean it can't contain invalid data... Or working with databases, it doesn't filter out malicious SQL code.

Comment: This should give you some insight - http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38071/how-reliable-is-asp-nets-request-validation-feature

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There is plenty of perfectly valid input in ASP.NET's eyes that could cause issues in your application if not dealt with correctly.

For example, if somebody passed some data in a request and you weren't correctly parameterizing queries in your data layer then this input:

```
x'; DROP TABLE users; --
```

Could result in this query:

```
SELECT FieldList
FROM Users
WHERE Email = 'x'; DROP TABLE Users; --
```

Oh noes! You've lost your Users table!

You should always treat user-input as hostile irrespective of request validation. [This](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/06/bypassing-aspnet-request-validation.html) demonstrates some scenarios whereby request validation wouldn't save your skin.

HTML encoding when you render user-provided input is important... Never render any untrusted input using `@Html.Raw` and be careful that your HtmlHelpers correctly encode anything coming from a user.

Defence in depth is important. Think of request validation as just one piece of that process.

Comment: I understand SQL injection. But I'm worrying just about web attacks like XSS.

Comment: @Hans then I'd update your question title. It implies you're asking about any old validation, not just for XSS.

Comment: @Hans Updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: Off topic: But as a precaution I don't give the app pool account access to drop tables or delete records.  So even if that query ran, it would get access denied on DROP Table Users;

Comment: @Ryios completely agree, but sadly not everybody follows best practice :(

Comment: @Ryios, true and good advice, but that doesn't stop SQL injection. UPDATE Users SET UserFirstName=(SELECT TOP 1 SSN+','+FirstName+','+'LastName+','+Address FROM Users) WHERE UserName='myusername' could arguably cause more damage. A DROP table I can restore a backup, leaking sensitive information... can't get it back.

Comment: True, I parameterize my sql though "PetaPoco, EF6, etc" and I also do everything through stored procedures.  My application code doesn't make a single raw SQL query except to call a stored proc or query a view.  No direct Table access.  In my stored procedures I have a 2nd security layer to determine if the passed in user has access to do what they are doing, the stored procedures either return row, no rows, or a return code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link about Xss on MSDN and Request Validation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: XSS attacks can only happen if your application allows users to submit data that other users will see.  Like a comment board, forum, User Profile, etc etc etc.

Request Validation should throw an error and reject the request on the post back if it detects markup of any kind in the post data script tags, b tags, any html tag, etc etc etc.  However most times people need to turn that off to allow rich text html editors.  In which case you'll need to make a custom request validator that still blocks scripts.

Comment: I see. I'm developing an application in which request validation is not bypassed at all. Now what? Sanitizing or not?

Comment: It should be safe against Xss then, but you can read the MSDN Article above in depth to be sure.

Comment: @Ryios *should* being the key thing here. If there's a vulnerability in the request validation feature (see link in my answer) then it would be possible for somebody to submit input that might be rendered elsewhere. Hence, make sure to HTML encode user-provided input at all times. Request validation doesn't skirt around that requirement.